# MYSQL issue 1025

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys

New in MYSQL I tried to create manualy a foreign key to existants tables because Django wouldn't modify it.

```
python2 manage.py sqlall <appname>
```

showed what I expected but

```
python2 manage.py syncdb
```

didn't do anything to tables.
Here are the models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  A_field1 = models.IntegerField(unique=True) # is not the primary key
  A_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  ...
  A_field3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# this method is to get the good name in the admin interface
def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name


class B(models.Model):
  B_field1 = models.FloatField()
  ...
  B_field2 = models.ForeignKey(A, to_field='A_field1')
```

But apparently I mistake the operation because it doesn't find the referenced field when I run the server, so I tried to delete the foreign key and I got this strange error:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE A DROP COLUMN A_field1;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './website/#sql-41e_740' to
'./website/<tablename>' (errno: 150)
```

Also, I tried

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE B DROP COLUMN B_field2;
```

But got pretty much the same error as above

Any Ideas ?

Here tables:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| A_field1     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| A_field2     | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| A_field3     | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
....   
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| B_field1        | double   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 ...
| B_field2        | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: This is not application issue, this is a data structure in DB problem. So, provide your table full structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't drop the foreign key using the column name,so:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable
```

This will show the name of your KEY,then drop it

```
 ALTER TABLE myTable DROP FOREIGN KEY its_name
```

Then also drop the column

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN myColumn;
```

Comment: Why django refuse to do it so?

Comment: Not django,Mysql error 150 is a badly formed foreign key.The column referenced by foreign key must be the exact same type,or adding a foreign key for something which does not exist.